# using inventory_hostname as part of a dictionary lookup

Tags: ansible

I would like to use inventory_hostname as part of a dictionary lookup to configure servers that use the same template, but with different variables

/etc/ansible/hosts

```
[nodes]
node1 ansible_host=192.168.0.2
```

roles/role/defaults/main.yml

```
node1:
  if1: eth1
  ip1: 1.1.1.1/11

node2:
  if1: eth4
  ip1: 4.4.4.4/44
```

roles/role/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ [inventory_hostname].[if1] }} end test  "
```

expected this to display `eth1` on the console but got the error

```
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'if1' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/ansible/roles/role/tasks/main.yml': line 6, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: test\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `vars`:

```
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ vars[ansible_hostname]['if1'] }} end test"
```